# Cannot start WCF Service - "The service cannot run your command at this time"

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I've been having issues getting a service to start.  I have 2 other services are identical in configuration in just about every way that start fine, but one of them refuses to start and I really need to get it to work today.  I can't see any difference in their implementation or config files. I'm receiving the following messages when attempting to start the service after installing it with InstallUtil:

The service is not responding to the control function

more help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186

NET HELPMSG 2186:

Explanation: The service cannot run your command at this time

If anyone has any thoughts and/or suggestions, they're GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: This is the message from the event viewer: An unhandled exception ('System.TypeLoadException') occurred in ExperienceSearchService.exe [5868]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking for any system/application events using EventVwr. The service could be crashing on startup or failing because of permissions for that particular service.

Try uninstalling and re-installing the service, with a reboot in between.

Also, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227404

Finally, do you have the MS Application verifier installed? If so, try to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've installed/uninstalled many times, but I'm going to try again with a reboot in between.  Here's the message from the event viewer:An unhandled exception ('System.TypeLoadException') occurred in ExperienceSearchService.exe [5868]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

Comment: OK, so, your service does not start because it is failing to load a DLL containing a type you depend on. See what your DLL dependencies are and why one of the DLLs is not accessable when you run your app as a service. Are all of the DLLs for the types you depend on in the same directory as your service? If not, this may be the problem (i.e., you depend on the path that you have as a user, which is not the same as the system path used for services that must run under the SYSTEM account)